# Can I use LoadBalancer type for kubernetes service on GCE not GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have VMs on GCP, which are normal Linux machines not GKE. I made kubernetes environment with kubeadm on this VMs and I am using `NodePort` type for my services.

But what I want to do is using type `LoadBalancer` for my services. Can I use `LoadBalancer` type with [GCP Clound Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing)? I searched on Google many times but most of the result are for GKE which I am not using.

Comment: Hi Ellisein welcome to S.F. Have you already tried [the out-of-tree GCP provider](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-gcp#readme)? they've been pushing to get the cloud providers out into their own deployments, but I don't know what the status is of that one

Answer (score 0):

Note that in GKE, Load Balancer alone will create a Network Load Balancer (layer 4) while Ingress will use HTTP(S) load balancer (layer7). I will assume they want to use layer 7 load balancing

Using Nodeport (possibly with manual port allocation) + configuring HTTP load balancer to use this port as backend is the obvious solution and IIUC what they might be currently doing.

Having Kubernetes automatically create a GCP HTTP(s) load balancer will require an ingress controller.

Our ingress-gce controller is actually [open source](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce).

There is some brief [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/docs/deploy/gce/README.md) mentioning how to run it on GCE.

Comment: As an observation, OP asked only about `LoadBalancer`, and didn't mention Ingress -- they're related, but distinct. If one goes with the "obvious solution," it places the burden upon the user to keep the Node list synced to the provisioned load balancer